# Dividing by a total from another table with missing column

Tags: sql, presto

Let's say we have two tables, our tables give user information for purchase/view on an e-commerce website.

One table `purchases` has the following format:

| country | itemid | device | num_purchases | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | ABC | iPhone11 | 2 | 2022-06-15 |
| USA | ABC | iPhoneX | 5 | 2022-06-15 |
| USA | DEF | iPhoneX | 8 | 2022-06-15 |
| UK | ABC | iPhone11 | 10 | 2022-06-15 |
| UK | DEF | iPhoneX | 20 | 2022-06-15 |

`itemid` can be repeated across countries/device

Another table `views` has the following format, with total number of views made by each country and device for the day:

| country | device | total_views | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | iPhone11 | 500 | 2022-06-15 |
| USA | iPhoneX | 400 | 2022-06-15 |
| UK | iPhone11 | 250 | 2022-06-15 |
| UK | iPhoneX | 150 | 2022-06-15 |

In the second table, it has information on the total views per day for each country and device, but *doesn't have information on itemid.*

After joining the table on country, device and day, we get:

| country | itemid | device | num_purchases | total_views | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | ABC | iPhone11 | 2 | 500 | 2022-06-15 |
| USA | ABC | iPhoneX | 5 | 400 | 2022-06-15 |
| USA | DEF | iPhoneX | 8 | 400 | 2022-06-15 |
| UK | ABC | iPhone11 | 10 | 250 | 2022-06-15 |
| UK | DEF | iPhone11 | 20 | 100 | 2022-06-15 |

If we want to know the *number of purchases / view for each country*, the issue arises with row 2 and 3.

The calculation for USA should be: (2 + 5 + 8 ) / (500+400)

**Desired output:**

| country | num_purchases per view | total_views | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | (2 + 5 + 8) / (500+400) | (500+400) | 2022-06-15 |
| UK | (10 + 20) / (250+100) | (250+100) | 2022-06-15 |

**However**, if I do a normal groupby and sum, for USA it will be **(2 + 5 + 8) / (500 + 400 + 400)** instead because of the duplicate row in the joined table

Is it possible to 'ignore' the second 400 when summing after joining?

Comment: Calculate the total (500+400) before joining the views to purchases

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,

you could calculate the total_per_country_per_day before joining it:

```
SELECT P.COUNTRY, P.ITEMID, P.DEVICE,P.NUM_PURCHASES, V1.TOTAL_PER_COUNTRY_DAY,P.DAY
FROM PURCHASES P
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT V.COUNTRY,SUM(V.TOTAL_VIEWS) AS TOTAL_PER_COUNTRY_DAY,V.DAY
  FROM VIEWS V
  GROUP BY V.COUNTRY, V.DAY
) AS V1 ON P.COUNTRY = V1.COUNTRY AND P.DAY = V1.DAY
```

It should return:

```
country itemid  device      num_purchases   TOTAL_PER_COUNTRY_DAY   DAY
USA     ABC     iPhone11    2                900          2022-06-15
USA     ABC     iPhoneX     5                900          2022-06-15
USA     DEF     iPhoneX     8                900          2022-06-15
UK      ABC     iPhone11    10               350          2022-06-15
UK      DEF     iPhone11    20               350          2022-06-15
```

Then sum up the num_purchases per country per day:

```
SELECT A.COUNTRY
,CAST(SUM(A.NUM_PURCHASES) AS FLOAT)/A.TOTAL_PER_COUNTRY_DAY AS num_purchases_per_view
, A.TOTAL_PER_COUNTRY_DAY,DAY
FROM
(
   SELECT P.COUNTRY, P.ITEMID, P.DEVICE,P.NUM_PURCHASES,V1.TOTAL_PER_COUNTRY_DAY,P.DAY
   FROM PURCHASES P
   LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT V.COUNTRY,SUM(V.TOTAL_VIEWS) AS TOTAL_PER_COUNTRY_DAY,V.DAY
     FROM VIEWS V
     GROUP BY V.COUNTRY, V.DAY
   ) V1 ON P.COUNTRY = V1.COUNTRY AND P.DAY = V1.DAY
) A
GROUP BY A.COUNTRY,A.TOTAL_PER_COUNTRY_DAY,DAY
```

Be careful of the data type when you do dividing, you may need to cast/convert it.

Here is the test sample:

[DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de3ba3a1db74520b6fb37d45df6b5c6e)

Comment: I want to make visualizations with the final table, which involves being able to aggregate for every feature (country, device, and a few others not included in question), does this mean I would have to calculate the total for every single feature before joining? So if I wanted to be able to get the purchases/view for each device and country I would have to add two more columns to the table  TOTAL_PER_COUNTRY_DAY and TOTAL_PER_DEVICE_DAY?

Comment: @codenoodles, it is hard to say because I dont know which data visualization tool you are using. But literally, you need to add the calculated column per each dimension. It is a new question so I recommend you to open a new question and tag 'data visualization'